# Create a New Instance of a Derived Class Not Knowing it's Type

Tags: instance, radix, derived-class, base-class, derived

If I have a class called "A" and I have two classes that derive from it lets say "B" and "C" how do I create a new instance of both B and C not knowing which is which. This probably sounds confusing so let me clarify and use similar code as mine.

Base class:

```
class A {
    stuff...
}
```

Derived classes:

```
class B : A{
    stuff...
}

class C : A {
    stuff...
}
```

Then in some other class I have:

```
class Z {
    void Derp() {
        foreach(A classA in listOfA's) {
            create new instance of derived class
        }
    }
}
```

I simply cannot just say `B = new B()` and `C = new C()` because maybe B isn't in the list at all or maybe there are three B's and one A in the list. Surly there is some way to do it but if not I could have a switch-case statement like:

```
class Z {
    void Derp() {
        foreach(A classA in listOfA's) {
            switch(classA) {
                case is B:
                    B = new B();
                    break;
                case is C:
                    C = new C();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to avoid doing it this way unless necessary because every time I create a new class that derives from class A I'll have to remember to add another case statement in there.

So how should I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Create a pure virtual factory method in the superclass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common C++ solution to this is the so-called [*virtual constructor idiom*](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/virtual-functions.html#faq-20.8): you define a virtual function called `clone` in the base class `A`, and then override it in `B` to return a new instance of `B` and in `C` to return a new instance of `C`.

If you need a blank instance instead of a clone, you could add a `newInstance` function that uses the default constructor.